# A kind of double expectation for conditional expectation

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Is it true that for measurable $g \geqslant 0$ or $g \in L^1$,

$$\int_{\Omega} \mathbf{E} [g (X, Y
(\omega)) \mid Y = Y (\omega)] \mathbf{P} \left( \text{d} \omega \right)
=\mathbf{E} [g (X, Y)]$$?

I proved this for simple $g$, and then tried to approximate more general $g$ using simple functions, but got stuck since $g$ is multivariate and I haven't encountered multivariate versions of step function approximations or monotone convergence before. Are there still versions of these in the multivariate case or is there a way to sidestep this?

(The motivation comes from the proof of [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97422/probability-distribution-of-functions-of-random-variables), in the first statement of the proof it appears to use something like the above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a proof sketch:

$1.$ First show that the formula is true when $g=1_{A \times B}$ for some Borel sets $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}$. This is not too hard.

$2.$ Show that the collection of all Borel sets $C \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ such that the formula holds true when $g=1_C$, forms a Dynkin-system. By $(1)$, this Dynkin system contains the $\pi$-system consisting of sets of the form $A \times B$, for Borel $A,B\subset \mathbb{R}$.

$3.$ Use the $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem together with $(1)$ and $(2)$, in order to show that the formula holds when $g=1_C$, for Borel sets $C \subset \mathbb{R}^2$.

$4.$ Extend to all nonnegative (or $L^1$) functions $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ by using approximation by simple functions and MCT.

(Actually, there is probably a more succinct way to prove it by using Fubini's theorem, but I don't really see it.)

Comment: Thanks, this is the approach I took but I forgot step 2 in my proof, I realized that monotone convergence works here as $g$ applied to $X, Y$ or $Y(\omega)$ still converges pointwise and is no longer multivariate.

Comment: Yeah sure no problem. I didn't actually verify all of the details in the above sketch, but I'm pretty sure that they work out nicely (hopefully).